# using css modules in react how can I pass a className as a prop to a component

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack-style-loader, css-modules, css-loader

If I have a react component and I want to pass in a className, how do I do this with CSS Modules. It currently just gives the className but not the hash generated css module name which I would get for 
`<div className={styles.tile + ' ' + styles.blue}>`

Here is my **Tile.js** component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import styles from './Tile.css';

class Tile extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <div className={styles.tile + ' ' + this.props.color}>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default Tile;
```

**Tile.css**

```
@value colors: "../../styles/colors.css";
@value blue, black, red from colors;

.tile {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

So as you can see I initialize this Tile wrapper component as follows in my Author Tile, but I want to pass a color prop into the component:

**AuthorTile.js**

```
return (
  <Tile orientation='blue'>
   <p>{this.props.title}</p>
   <img src={this.props.image} />
  </Tile>
);
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From the docs:

> Avoid using multiple CSS Modules to describe a single element.
>   https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules#multiple-css-modules

```
@value colors: "../../styles/colors.css";
@value blue, black, red from colors;

.tile {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.black {
    composes: tile;
    background-color: black;
}

.blue {
    composes: tile;
    background-color: blue;
}

.red {
    composes: tile;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Then `<div className={styles[this.props.color]}` should do the job, e.g:

```
render: function(){
  // ES2015
  const className = styles[this.props.color];

  // ES5
  var className = '';

  if (this.props.color === 'black') {
    className = styles.black;
  }

  return (
    <div className={className}>
      {this.props.children}
    </div>
}
```

Comment: How do you propose having multiple color backgrounds for this Tile component, which can be defined when you initialize it?

Comment: What you have done is not a bad approach to using composition with css modules, but still my main concern is how do I use the passes in color for the Tile, e.g. `<Tile color='black'>` How does this translate in the Tile? `<div className={this.props.color}>` is not going to work because it expects `{styles.blue}` not `blue` which would become something like `components_Tile__blue__abc5436`

Comment: If you're using ES2015 `<div className={styles[this.props.color]}` should do the job. If not, just check for `this.props.color` value e.g `var className = ''; if (this.props.color === 'black') { className = styles.black; }`.

Comment: `<div className={styles[this.props.color]}` did it. You are awesome, if you answer with this I can mark it as accepted. I actually thought about doing this but messed the syntax up first time around. Thanks

Comment: if I am using ES5 or 6 and I have e.g. 10 classnames, do I have to check through all of them to create the right styles.x ? Isn't there any better way to solve this problem?

Comment: what if I have more than 2 states, eg: `tile` `blue` `selected` ?